# How do I set a SQL Server 2012/14 column of type geography to null?

Tags: c#, sql-server, geospatial

In SQL Server 2014 I have a `geography` column that stores a point.

How to I set the value of this column via C# to null?

If I do `[column-name] = null` I get this error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
>   System.FormatException: 24112: The well-known text (WKT) input is
>   empty. To input an empty instance, specify an empty instance of one of
>   the following types: Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint,
>   MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, CircularString, CompoundCurve,
>   CurvePolygon or GeometryCollection.
>
> System.FormatException:
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader..ctor(SqlChars chars,
>   GeoDataSink sink)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType
>   type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Parse(SqlString s)

Comment: Would be better if we see your C# code as well..

Comment: I think you cannot set the value to null instead you can set as default (0,0) point.. like this.. geography::STPointFromText('POINT (0 0)', 4326)

Comment: what happens if you set your column to var geo = new SqlGeometry();? this would create an empty geom I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`SqlGeometry.Null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.null.aspx). Also, here are some [interesting differences](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/sql-server-spatial-empty-vs-null/) between NULL and Empty.

Using that is the equivalent of the following query in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE table
SET [column-name] = geometry::[Null]
WHERE ...some conditions...
```

Although, in TSQL using NULL works fine as well.